# How do I query the value of a DB option in Sybase without using sp_helpdb status?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I need to get the dboption value for All Sybase Database.

but without using `sp_helpdb` stored procedures.

```
1> sp_helpdb
2> go
name             db_size       owner         dbid         created         status
asdfg_syb        30.0 MB       sa             4          Feb 08, 2017     **no options set**
db01             21010.0 MB    sa             5          Feb 14, 2017     **no options set**
master           13.0 MB       sa             1          Feb 07, 2017     **mixed log and data**
model            3.0 MB        sa             3          Feb 07, 2017     **mixed log and data**
sybsystemdb      3.0 MB        sa             31513      Feb 07, 2017     **mixed log and data**
sybsystemprocs   132.0 MB      sa             31514      Feb 07, 2017     **trunc log on chkpt, mixed log and data**
tempdb           4.0 MB        sa             2          Feb 14, 2017     **select into/bulkcopy/pllsort, trunc log on chkpt, mixed log and data**

(1 row affected)
(return status = 0)
```

I tried using in sysdatabase status but it looks complex.

can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

sp_helpdb gets its information from internal status bits, and yes, that can be complicated. Nothing stops you from making a copy of the sp_helpdb code and stripping it down to the minimum level you need.